# Python: urllib.request.urlopen Is not working properly

Tags: python, decode, urllib, urlencode, urlopen

I don't know why this code does not work.
When I print the list "videos" and "search results" to see what is happening, they are both empty. This is why the if statement is never reached as you can see in the screenshot.

```
# Query youtube results based on the songs entered in the text file
def find_video_urls(self, songs):
       videos = list()
       for song in songs:
            self.update_text_widget("\nSong - " + song + " - Querying youtube results ...")
        
            query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query": song})
            with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string) as html_content:

                # retrieve all videos that met the song name criteria
                search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())

                # only take the top result
                if len(search_results) != 0:
                    videos.append("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])
                    self.update_text_widget("\nSong - " + song + " - Found top result!")
return videos
```

[GUI Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py3rj.png)

Comment: have you printed `html_content` to see what you got?

Comment: When I print "html_content" I get this: <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x00000217B97FB7F0>

Comment: i meant `html_content.read().decode()`... there probably isn't any link to your videos in the page because urllib doesn't handle javascript

Comment: and do yourself a favor: don't parse html with regular expressions.

Comment: When I print html_content.read().decode('utf-8') I get all the HTML code of the website I am trying to reach

Comment: no you don't. you maybe got a huge html page but the links you're expecting are not there. they're stored in json format `{"url":"/watch?v=_Yhyp-_hX2s","webPageType":"WEB_PAGE_TYPE_WATCH","rootVe":3832}` that's why the small modification pythonman did to your regex works and not yours

Answer (score 1):

Hi Vigilante I will share a code on how to do it with requests. Maybe you can implement it in your code.

```
import re
import requests

def find_video_urls(songs):
    videos = list()
    for song in songs:
        with requests.session() as ses:
            r = ses.get('http://www.youtube.com/results', params={"search_query": song})
            search_results = re.findall(b'(/watch\?v=.{11})\"', r.content, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
            print(search_results)
            
            # only take the top result
            if len(search_results) != 0:
                videos.append(b"".join([b'https://www.youtube.com', search_results[0]]))
    return videos

print(find_video_urls(['Eminem - Lose Yourself']))
```